# Why are all the buttons on a QWidget not showing?

Tags: python, pyqt5, file-manager

I am a python Intermediate but I have missed out a few basic parts of python. I am currently learning PyQt5 but don't want to create a window using subclasses yet. I have tried PyQt5 before but never really understood it and was copying and pasting everything without understanding the fundamentals. I am currently working on a very basic file manager in python, but I am having some problems displaying folder buttons.

I am automatically creating buttons depending on how many files and folders there are (I am making all of them folder icons for now) and adding them to a QWidget. Here is the section of my code which is not working expectedly:

```
for x in files:
    folderbutton = QPushButton(w)
    folderbutton.setIcon(foldericon)
    folderbutton.setIconSize(QSize(100, 100))
    folderbutton.setGeometry(folposx, folposy, 100, 100)
    folposx += 10
    if folposx >= 1919:
        folposx = 0
        folposy += 120
```

the for loop loops through all the files. `folposx` and `folposy` are defined earlier in the code. They are both set to zero. `folderbutton` is what temporarily defines each `QPushButton`. `foldericon` is defined earlier in the code as a `QIcon`. After defining the position and size of the button, the code adds 10 to `folposx`, so the next button is beside it. If the button is over the screen's width, the Y value of the button increases and the X value of the button resets, making a new line for the folder buttons.

The above is what I expected to happen, although the actual result was [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zplxf.png)

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could help me, and if anyone needs my full code, I am happy to edit this question with it.

Thanks, Zayan.

**Edit**: the below is my full code, all of the code is needed to reproduce my problem.

```py
import os
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

files = os.listdir()

def window():
    global files
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QWidget()
    w.setStyleSheet('background: black; color: white;')
    folposx = 0
    folposy = 0
    w.setGeometry(0, 0, 1919, 1079)
    foldericon = QIcon('C:/Users/HP/OneDrive/Python_Projects/aura_explorer/folder.png') 
    pixmap = foldericon.pixmap(100, 100)
    for x in files:
        folderbutton = QPushButton(w)
        folderbutton.setIcon(foldericon)
        folderbutton.setIconSize(QSize(100, 100))
        folderbutton.setGeometry(folposx, folposy, 100, 100)
        folposx += 10
        if folposx >= 1919:
            folposx = 0
            folposy += 120
            

    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
   window()
```

Comment: You're most probably trying to do the above when the window has been already shown (or at least after `show()` has been called). If a parent has already been shown, any children created for it without being added to a layout needs to be *explicitly* shown (by calling `show()` or `setVisible(True)`). Note that widgets should always use [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html), but for your purpose pure widgets are probably not the best choice, and a QListView set in icon mode is certainly a better choice. In any case, please provide a [mre] so that we can better understand the problem.

Comment: Maybe a bit more of code would be useful indeed. Also not sure what's not working in the screenshot. Your problem, is it the placement of the buttons (being on top of each other) or the fact is that only one button is created ? Did you share the full for loop ? Because within the loop you need to add the button to a widget using something like `layout.addWidget(folderbutton)`

Comment: Tricotou, I am not sure if the buttons are on top of each other, but I doubt it as when I change the amount of spacing between buttons (Line 24 of my full code) the button moves to different places. The problem is more likely to be only one button showing.

Comment: Musicamante, my full code shows that I am not creating a child after show() has been called. I will reasearch layout managers and see if they are what I need. As per your request, I have added a Minimal Reproducible Example, and I can provide any other information as per your or anyone else's requests. P.s. I remember you always helping me out on all my questions, so thank you very much.

Comment: if you don't use `layout managers` then it doesn't know how to organize items in window and you have to use `setGeometry()` on your own to organize items. If you use `layout managers` (or special widgets to display many object) then it will automatically organize items - and it will automatically organize them again when you resize window.

Comment: Furas, thank you for explaining this, I really do appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The cause(s) of the problem

What you see in the image is caused by the following factors:

- you set a stylesheet for the parent widget (`w`) without proper [selector types](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types), with the result that the black background is propagated to all its children;
- you only shift `folposx` by 10 pixels;
- by default, buttons have a margin between the border and their contents (the icon and/or the label) which normally defaults to 5-10 pixels for each side;
- setting the icon size results in the buttons having their final (minimum) sizes incremented by the above margins; in your case, the buttons *should* have a size of about 110x110 in order to allow the displaying of the border, but since you're forcing their geometry to 100x100, the borders are automatically hidden as there's no space left to show them;
- the icon probably has a "padding" of a few transparent pixels around the actual "drawing" of the folder;

The buttons are there, but every new button is added only slightly to the right than the position of the previous one; since the forced geometry doesn't allow borders, you only see the background of each button, and only the 10 pixels on the left of each one: every newly stacked button completely hides the rest of the underlying button, resulting in a seamless black strip. Only the final button is completely visible, since it's on top of the stack.

Try the following change:

```py
    ...
    for x in files:
        ...
        folderbutton.setStyleSheet('border: 1px solid red;')
        ...
```

And you'll probably see something like this:

[image]

<sup>Note that in this case the border is visible because of the way Qt style sheets work.</sup>

As you can see, buttons are stacked each one on top of the other. It's like having stickers with a black background and an image shown in them (but with some blank margin around it): if you put them one over the other, only slightly moving them on the right of the one below them, you'll end up with a lot of black on the left of the topmost sticker, which is the result of all the visible left edges of each underlying sticker.

### A possible solution

Now, considering all the above, you should always adjust the horizontal and vertical shifts using the button size *hint*. Also, you must remember that you need to check if you're not going beyond the right edge *before* setting its geometry, not after, otherwise you'll probably end up with a partially visible row on the right.

Here is a better implementation of your code:

```py
    folposx = folposy = rowheight = 0
    for x in files[:40]:
        folderbutton = QPushButton(w)
        folderbutton.setIcon(foldericon)
        folderbutton.setIconSize(QSize(100, 100))

        # let the button adjust its size based on its needs
        folderbutton.adjustSize()

        width = folderbutton.width()
        height = folderbutton.height()
        if folposx + width > w.width():
            folposx = 0
            folposy += rowheight
        else:
            rowheight = max(rowheight, height)

        folderbutton.setGeometry(folposx, folposy, width, height)

        folposx += width
```

Unfortunately, this won't solve an important issue: the widgets will always keep the geometries you explicitly set, and if the window is resized you will end up with a lot of empty space on the right (when making the window wider) or having lots of elements partially or completely invisible (if the window becomes narrower).

### The layout alternative

In theory, you *could* use a layout manager (possibly, QGridLayout), but that will only partially solve the problem: if the window is made very wide, there will be a lot of unused space in each row, since the grid has a fixed column count.

A possibility could be to use a "Flow layout", which Qt doesn't provide on its own, and has to be subclassed from QLayout (see the [official PySide6 example](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtforpython-dev/examples/example_widgets_layouts_flowlayout.html) or a similar implementation [for PyQt5](https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/blob/master/examples/layouts/flowlayout.py)). In theory it allows to automatically "wrap" widgets as soon as there is no horizontal space left.

This won't solve a major problem, no matter the layout type you use: if there are too many items, the window will eventually grow in height, possibly beyond the screen size.
You could then use a QScrollArea, create a container QWidget (applied using `QScrollArea.setWidget()`), set the above layout on it, and add the buttons to that layout.

### Still, not enough

Unfortunately, we still haven't solved *all* problems; for instance:

- your buttons only have icons, but you'll probably need to display the *names* of each file or folder, and names can be *very long*; you may end up with rows with just a few (or even one) "icon", because its name is too long to make another button fit that row;
- while the program is running, some files or folders may be renamed, added or removed within the same path you're showing (by you, by another program, or even the OS);
- if you want to allow navigation through directories, you have to be very careful in always deleting the current widgets, otherwise the memory usage may dramatically increase over time;
- following the above point, you will possibly be recreating the same contents over and over when entering and exiting a directory, and each "browsing" may require a lot of time, freezing the program in the meanwhile;

With all that in mind, it's clear that none of the solutions above is effective.

Luckily, Qt *does* provide an alternative: the Qt model/view approach, through QListView and QFileSystemModel. Item views are much better for these purposes, as they are faster and normally require less memory than using actual widgets.

QListView is normally used to vertically display items, but it's actually able to show a mono dimensional model (like a list) in a 2D space, including arranging its items horizontally, eventually wrapping each "line" as soon as there is no space left.
QFileSystemModel is a "Qt-model interface" to the underlying file system, providing consistent entries and even appropriate icons on its own. Its asynchronous and caching capabilities also prevent blocking when entering or exiting folders with thousands of entries.

The benefit is that you don't have to care about item layout anymore, and the *view* will always provide scrolling capabilities whenever necessary.

Entering directories via doubleclick is even simpler: you only need to set the root index of the view based on the directory you want to show, which can be easily done using the view's signals or even externally (to navigate upper levels).

```py
def window():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('windows')
    fileView = QListView()
    fileView.setStyleSheet('''
        QListView { 
            background: black; 
        }
        QListView:item {
            color: white; 
        }
    ''')

    fileView.setIconSize(QSize(100, 100))
    fileView.setViewMode(QListView.IconMode)
    fileView.setResizeMode(QListView.Adjust)
    fileView.setWordWrap(True)
    fileView.setSpacing(10)
    # eventually set a fixed item size (this may be a problem 
    # as it will elide the text for long names):
    # fileView.setUniformItemSizes(True)

    model = QFileSystemModel()
    root = QDir.currentPath()
    model.setRootPath(root)
    fileView.setModel(model)
    fileView.setRootIndex(model.index(root))

    def enterDir(index):
        if model.isDir(index):
            fileView.setRootIndex(index)
    fileView.doubleClicked.connect(enterDir)

    screen = QApplication.primaryScreen()
    geo = screen.availableGeometry()
    geo.setSize(geo.size() * .8)
    geo.moveCenter(screen.availableGeometry().center())
    fileView.setGeometry(geo)

    fileView.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And here is the result:
[image]

As you can see, the width is not always consistent (word wrapping only happens when the name contains spaces), but it's still usable, and far better than doing everything on your own.

<sup>A final, unrelated note about "[I] don't want to create a window using subclasses yet". While Python allows functional programming, it still is an Object Oriented language, and you also have to consider that aspect when using an *extremely* OOP oriented toolkit as Qt is. While using simple functions may work fine for simple cases, basing your whole code on it may become a *huge* obstacle in the long run, complicating things where they could be way simpler if done with proper awareness.

I strongly suggest you to begin to use subclassing as soon as possible, instead of trying to avoid it, because your "precautious" intention may require implementing unnecessarily convoluted approaches that often result in unexpected behaviors (not to mention that some things can *only* be done with subclassing), especially if you're trying to use things such as `global` without really considering their implications.</sup>

Comment: This is the most detailed explanation of anything I've ever gotten, thank you so much. I do have some questions though. Is it possible to set your own icons, and can I make the ```QListView``` start at a certain x value? Thank you once again, you basically have done all my work

Comment: @CrimsonFox88 Using QFileSystemModel, icons are internally chosen based on the file type. You can eventually set your own [`QFileIconProvider`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileiconprovider.html) on the model and return different icons based on your own needs; coincidentally, in order to do that, you must use subclassing ;-) In order to override the positioning of items, you can use the `padding` property in the QSS; add the following in the `QListView { }` definition: `padding-left: 50px;`.

Comment: @musicmante, haha, alright, I'll use subclasses. I do wonder something though... if you set your ```QFileIconProvider``` to a folder with some of the icons in it, will ```QFileSystemModel``` get the rest of the icons internally?

Comment: @CrimsonFox88 QFileIconProvider is set on the model, and returns the icon for a given file/directory; generally, the location is irrelevant. When an icon provider is set on QFileSystemModel, the latter calls [`icon()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileiconprovider.html#icon-1) on the former, using the QFileInfo corresponding to the file system node (file, folder, drive, etc.). By subclassing and overriding `icon()` you get a QFileInfo entry, and you may chose to return a different icon based on the entry name or path, otherwise just return the default behavior: `return super().icon(info)`.

Comment: Note that, in reality, you can do the same directly from the model: by subclassing QFileSystemModel and overriding `data()`, check if the `role` is `Qt.DecorationRole`, get the actual QFileInfo with `self.fileInfo(index)` and decide if you want to return a custom icon from that, otherwise just return the default behavior similarly to the above: `return super().data(index, role)`.

Comment: Alright, that's good to know, thanks! Also, I tried searching up examples of using custom icons and I used a subclass of ```QFileIconProvider```, overriding ```icon()``` and checking if the second parameter is a directory (```if fileInfo.isDir():```), and if so, return a ```QIcon```. Otherwise I return ```QFileIconProvider.icon(self, fileInfo)```. When I run this I do not see any icons for directories, should I make a new question about this?

Comment: @CrimsonFox88 Yes, you should.